# How to save text to speech to wav file using VB6 and SAPI 4

Tags: vb6, text-to-speech, sapi

I've managed to record to a file using this method:

Include the Microsoft Direct Speech Synthesis Component. A component shows on the toolbar resembling a mouth

Put that component on a form and write some code for the click event:

```
DirectSS1.filename = "audiofile.wav"
DirectSS1.Speak "Insert a long text here"
```

That works but it has 2 problems for me:

1. It takes too long to generate the wav file, because the component
   reads the text at normal speaking speed.  I need to generate the
   file faster.
2. It is Asynchronous. I need somehow to wait until the file is
       ready in order to continue.

(Can't use SAPI 5 as I need to use SAPI 4 voices.)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The VB6 component you are using had been Engineered to do exactly what you describe. It is not an API to simply accept a string and create a WAV file instantaniously.

Therefore, you will need to investigate newer technologies and not use the Visual Basic 6 component to do what you're trying to do. I'm sure there are various alternatives although a Google search will be your starting point.